# How to save .mp3 from pyttsx3 to certain location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

```
def finalvoice():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()  
    raw_voice = Path("post_data.json").read_text()
    final_voice = json.loads(raw_voice.replace("post_body",""))
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)  
    engine.say(final_voice)
    output_path = r'C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\reddit video\test.mp3'
    engine.save_to_file(final_voice, output_path)
    engine.runAndWait()
finalvoice()
```

The program runs but I cant find test.mp3 in the given directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bit late but the save_to_file accepts a filename and not a path as the second argument.
i think you should try using the os library to exchange the file path of the save_to_file function to what every directory you want it to land in.